# How to debug when application works fine in emulator but fails in actual phones?

Tags: android, debugging

How can i debug when application works without error in emulator but force closes while doing SQLite operations on some screens?

Comment: Which SQLite operations? why force close? post logcat output here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should connect the phone to your development machine and look at Logcat (or use the debugger) to see what is going on in the stack trace. You can also install an app (like CatLog) on the phone to view the log.

Answer (score 3):

1. Connect your phone to your dev machine
2. Make sure the emulator is not running
3. Open a command prompt and run `adb logcat`
4. Use application on your phone and trigger the error
5. Review the resulting stack trace in the logcat output

You can also view the logcat output in Eclipse via the debug or DDMS perspective.

Answer (score 2):

You just connect you phone and use debugger. When it is open just choose your phone...you can use and logcat too...

Answer (score 2):

Everyone else commented about the technical tools available, so I'll try to explain the process we have with our app. Our app is pretty widely used, so we have a bunch of different devices to consider.

- **Create a beta group.** There are a lot of devices, and it's impossible to test on all of them yourself unless your company has very deep pockets and you have a lot of time to test. Get a group of users together who are ok with things breaking, and ask them to beta test.
- **Look at what's different.** This one seems obvious, but it's surprising how often this trips us up. If an app isn't working on certain devices, what's different about those devices? We once had a bug that only occurred when the app was in landscape mode, so we saw it mostly on devices that default to landscape mode. When you're trying to find the cause of a bug, ask yourself what the difference is between the scenario where the app doesn't work and the scenario where the app does work.
- **Use the tech available.** Sometimes, the last two don't catch all the problems. Sometimes, you get a weird edge case. We had 2.3 devices that didn't implement a deprecated method-- even though the method was deprecated in 3.0. For whatever reason, they didn't implement the method and left us without its replacement, so we had to use a backwards compatibility package. But the only reason this came to light was because we got access to the logcat reports from users who experienced the bug. Moral of the story: **manufacturers do weird stuff.**

You're not going to be able to catch everything. There are just too many subtle and non-sensical differences. But (especially with beta testing) you should be able to catch 99.99% of the problems before they happen.